# Python memory consumption of objects and process

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I wrote the following code:

```
from hurry.size import size
from pysize import get_zise
import os
import psutil
def load_objects():
   process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
   print "start method"
   process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
   print "process consumes " + size(process.memory_info().rss)
   objects = make_a_call()
   print "total size of objects is " + (get_size(objects))
   print "process consumes " + size(process.memory_info().rss)
   print "exit method"

def main():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print "process consumes " + size(process.memory_info().rss)
    load_objects()
    print "process consumes " + size(process.memory_info().rss)
```

`get_size()` returns the memory consumption of the objects using [this](https://github.com/bosswissam/pysize) code.

I get the following prints:

```
process consumes 21M
start method
total size of objects is 20M
process consumes 29M
exit method
process consumes 29M
```

1. How come the objects consumed 20M if the process consumed only 8M more?
2. If I exit a method shouldn't the memory decreased back to 21 as the garbage collector will clear the consumed memory?

Comment: For second question, gc won't clear memory immediately as there is a cost of garbage collecting.

Comment: I read that it would run ONLY if reaches threshold - is it right?

Comment: No, it's not true. There is a complicated policy for garbage collection. ref: https://www.quora.com/How-does-garbage-collection-in-Python-work-What-are-the-pros-and-cons

Comment: BTW, to use python pythonically, you need to believe that the underlying mechanics work well enough. Touching them will make you feel plain... For example, even you explicitly call `gc.collect()`, it won't work all the time.

Comment: for 1, what is your issue, 8m vm overhead is too small? for 2, gc works, but it won't release back to os.

Comment: what kind of objects does make_a_call load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Most likely this is because there's inaccuracy in your code.

Here's a fully working (python 2.7) example that has the same problem (I've slightly updated the original code for simplicity's sake)

```
from hurry.filesize import size
from pysize import get_size
import os
import psutil


def make_a_call():
    return range(1000000)

def load_objects():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print "start method"
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print"process consumes ", size(process.memory_info().rss)
    objects = make_a_call()
    # FIXME
    print "total size of objects is ", size(get_size(objects))
    print "process consumes ", size(process.memory_info().rss)
    print "exit method"

def main():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print "process consumes " + size(process.memory_info().rss)
    load_objects()
    print "process consumes " + size(process.memory_info().rss)


main()
```

Here's the output:

```
process consumes 7M
start method
process consumes  7M
total size of objects is  30M
process consumes  124M
exit method
process consumes 124M
```

The difference is **~100Mb**

And here's the fixed version of the code:

```
from hurry.filesize import size
from pysize import get_size
import os
import psutil


def make_a_call():
    return range(1000000)

def load_objects():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print "start method"
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print"process consumes ", size(process.memory_info().rss)
    objects = make_a_call()
    print "process consumes ", size(process.memory_info().rss)
    print "total size of objects is ", size(get_size(objects))
    print "exit method"

def main():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print "process consumes " + size(process.memory_info().rss)
    load_objects()
    print "process consumes " + size(process.memory_info().rss)


main()
```

And here is the updated output:

```
process consumes 7M
start method
process consumes  7M
process consumes  38M
total size of objects is  30M
exit method
process consumes 124M
```

Did you spot the difference? You're calculating object sizes before measuring the final process size and it leads to additional memory consumption. 
Lets check why it might be happening - here's the sources of 
https://github.com/bosswissam/pysize/blob/master/pysize.py:

```
import sys
import inspect

def get_size(obj, seen=None):
    """Recursively finds size of objects in bytes"""
    size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    obj_id = id(obj)
    if obj_id in seen:
        return 0
    # Important mark as seen *before* entering recursion to gracefully handle
    # self-referential objects
    seen.add(obj_id)
    if hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        for cls in obj.__class__.__mro__:
            if '__dict__' in cls.__dict__:
                d = cls.__dict__['__dict__']
                if inspect.isgetsetdescriptor(d) or inspect.ismemberdescriptor(d):
                    size += get_size(obj.__dict__, seen)
                break
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        size += sum((get_size(v, seen) for v in obj.values()))
        size += sum((get_size(k, seen) for k in obj.keys()))
    elif hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        size += sum((get_size(i, seen) for i in obj))
    return size
```

Lots of things are happening here!
The most notable one is that it holds all the objects it has seen in a set to resolve circular references. If you remove that line it won't each that much memory in either case.

2. First of all, this behavior heavily depends on whether you use CPython or something else.  As of CPython, this may happen because it's not always possible to give memory back to the OS immediately.

Here's a good [article](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm) on the subject, quoting:

> If you create a large object and delete it again, Python has probably
>   released the memory, but the memory allocators involved don’t
>   necessarily return the memory to the operating system, so it may look
>   as if the Python process uses a lot more virtual memory than it
>   actually uses.

Answer (score 3):

1. Why would the process *need* to consume an overhead greater than 8M?
2. Garbage collection does not necessarily happen immediately. [See the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> Objects are never explicitly destroyed; however, when they become
>   unreachable they may be garbage-collected. An implementation is
>   allowed to postpone garbage collection or omit it altogether — it is a
>   matter of implementation quality how garbage collection is
>   implemented, as long as no objects are collected that are still
>   reachable.
>
> CPython implementation detail: CPython currently uses a
>   reference-counting scheme with (optional) delayed detection of
>   cyclically linked garbage, which collects most objects as soon as they
>   become unreachable, but is not guaranteed to collect garbage
>   containing circular references. See the documentation of the [gc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#module-gc) module
>   for information on controlling the collection of cyclic garbage. Other
>   implementations act differently and CPython may change. Do not depend
>   on immediate finalization of objects when they become unreachable (so
>   you should always close files explicitly).